# Reg: Javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I match the pattern `abc_[someArbitaryStringHere]_xyz?`

To clarify, I would want the regex to match strings of the nature:

abc_xyz, abc_asdfsdf_xyz, abc_32rwrd_xyz etc.

I tried with `/abc_*_xyz/` but this seems to be an incorrect expression.

Comment: you need to capture `[someArbitraryStringHere]` from the match ?

Comment: You need a dot in front of the star: `/^abc_.*_xyz$/` (and start/end tokens too)

Comment: but he want to match strings with num

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
/^abc(?:_.*_|_)xyz$/
```

Be sure to include the `^` and `$`, they guard the beginning and end of the string. Otherwise strings like "123abc_foo_xyz" will match.

`(?:_.*_|_)` Is a non-capture group that matches either `_[someArbitaryStringHere]_` or a single `_`

Comment: Matches `abc__xyz` (two underscores)

Comment: From my understanding the expression should match `abc__xyz`, however it should also match `abc_xyz`

Answer (score 1):

Your regex would be,

```
abc(?:(?:_[^_]+)+)?_xyz
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pS5cD9/2)

Comment: Matches `abc__xyz` (two underscores)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `abc_xyz` is indeed a string you want to match, and isn't just a typo, then your regex is:

```
/abc(?:_[^_]+)?_xyz/
```

This will match `abc`, then *optionally* match a `_` followed by greedily matching anything but `_`s. After this optional part, it will match the ending `_xyz`.

If this is to match an entire string (as opposed to just extracting substrings from a bigger string), then you can just put `^` at the start and `$` at the end, like so:

```
/^abc(?:_[^_]+)?_xyz$/
```

EDIT: Just noticed that JavaScript doesn't support possessive matching, only greedy. Changed `++` to `+`.

---

EDIT2: The above regexes also assume that your "arbitrary string" does not contain more underscores. They can be expanded to allow more rules.

For example, to allow just anything, a truly arbitrary string, try:

```
/abc(?:_.*)?_xyz/ or /^abc(?:_.*)?_xyz$/
```

But if you want to be really clever, and disallow consecutive underscores, you can do:

```
/abc(?:_[^_]+)*_xyz/ or /^abc(?:_[^_]+)*_xyz$/
```

And lastly, if you want to "only allow letters or numbers" in your arbitrary strings, just replace `[^_]` with `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Comment: Thank you @hwnd - I was worried the plethora of answers would bury mine XD

Comment: Anytime @NiettheDarkAbsol

Comment: This doesn't match strings where the "arbitrary string" contains underscores, like `abc_foo_bar_xyz`.

Comment: it won't matches `abc_asdfs_df_xyz`

Comment: @PatrikOldsberg True, however since none of the example strings included `_` in the arbitrary string, I excluded it here. If the arbitrary string can in fact contain `_`, then simply replace `[^_]` with `.`

Comment: If OP wants to match strings like that then OP needs to be more specific when throwing arbitrary string out in context.

Comment: but the only good thing is the + , due to it force a string between but he never says accepts special chars between abx_X_xyz

Comment: Edited with more possibilities.

Comment: its true @AvinashRaj need to be more specific as I this regex will match abc_!"@$%&/()=?¡_xyz . if you need something specific like \w which will accepts alphanumeric and  underscore

Answer (score 0):

The '*' mean you will match 0 or more. but of what?

```
   /abc_[a-z0-9]*_xyz/im
```

The DOT. will match any character ANY.

```
/abc_(.*)_xyz/im
```

Comment: `m` is not appropriate here. It is meaningless without any `^` or `$`.

Comment: I don't think so. M is multi line. ^begin of line $ end of line. they are different

Comment: What, exactly, do you think "multiline" means?

Comment: will not end at the break line ? it can continuously match a long space if the expression requires it, but you need m if you use ^ or $

Comment: `m` modifies the behaviour of `^` and `$`, making them match the start and end of a line rather than the start and end of the entire string. In this case, you have no `^` or `$` in your regex, so the modifier is useless.

Comment: I don't always use ^ or $, but like when I compress with m.. can't see your point of useless

Comment: It's very simple: `m` modifies the behaviour of `^` and `$`. But if there are no `^` or `$` in your regex, then `m` has nothing to modify, making it useless.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for at least one underscore as well if you want to match `abc_xyz`:

```
abc_+.*xyz
```